# ruby super keyword in initialize throws ArgumentError

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm learning ruby from a book based on ruby 1.9 but currently I'm using 2.2

I have two classes (from the book)

```rb
class Point
    def initialize(x,y)
        @x,@y = x,y
    end
end

class Point3D < Point
    def initialize(x,y,z)
        super(x,y)
        @z = z
    end
end
```

however when I call `Point3D.new(0,1,2)` the ruby interpreter raises a `ArgumentError` that says `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`.

Why is this happening?

EDIT

I've omitted to say that the Point class is in another `require`d file.

I've tried to call

```
require "./Point.rb"

point = Point.new(0,1)
puts point
```

which work as expected

then added the Point3D class as described over and tried to call

```
require "./Point.rb"

class Point3D < Point
...
end

point1 = Point3D.new(0,1,2)
puts point1
```

which raises the ArgumentError.

If I put the two classes in the same file (Point3D.rb) however this problem does not happen, but if I put the Point3D class in Point.rb the error remains.

Comment: 2.1.2 and 2.2.0 both seem to work without issue. Can only see two situations where you would get that error - super being called without arguments and initializing Point with 3 args.

Comment: from my code it's clear that I'm not doing that.

Comment: 2.1, 2.2 @linux: not reproducible.

Comment: Works well for 1.9.3

Comment: Well, instead of `require "./Point.rb"` use `require_relative "Point"`

Comment: tried it, still not working

Comment: Your edit is unclear. "If I put the two classes in the same file (Point3D.rb) however this problem does not happen, but if I put the Point3D class in Point.rb the error remains." Not sure what the distinction is here. You have a point.rb file which contains a definition for the point3d class but not the point class?

Answer (score 0):

I understood what the problem was.

The book made an example on how to create an `initialize` overload

```
class Point
    def initialize(x,y)
        @x,@y = x,y
    end

    def self.new(x,y)
        #other stuff
        super
    end
end
```

and it was missing the `super` call from `Point3D`

I've commented the `self.new` and `Point` is working as expected.

It is interesting to note that if you add methods to `Point` in the file *Point.rb* like this

```
class << Point
    def to_s
        "foo"
    end
end
```

Point.rb works correctly.

Comment: A good practise is to try and run the exact code you post here and see if it works without any other code. Otherwise we're clueless as to your problem.